# Time complexity of the recursive algorithm each recursion takes O(N)

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have a algorithm, the pseudo code below:

```
def foo(n):
    if n == 0
    return;

    // Loop below take O(N)
    for(i=0; i<n:i++){
   .... 
    }
    foo(n-1):
```

The idea is that each recursion takes n time, and there are n recursions.

The total time should be like 1 + 2 3 + 4 +5 + ... +n

Can it be proved as O(n*n)?

Comment: Yea that seems like O(n^2).  Inner-loop runs n-times, recursion happens n-times.

Comment: What about profiling to validate your hypothesis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is `O(n^2)`.

The sum of `n` natural numbers is: `n * (n+1) / 2`, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF). Which is different to `n^2` by a [constant factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant), so `O(n * (n+1) / 2) == O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have `n` iterations in the `for` loop, then the function will repeat with `n-1`, `n-2`, ..., 0.

It's easy to see that `n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = (n+1) * n/2 = (n^2 + n)/2 = O(n^2)`.

To evaluate Big O, that is, the complexity of the worst case, remember you have to ignore the all the coeficients, constants and lower power terms:

```
(n^2 + n)/2 = (1/2) * (n^2 + n)

O( (1/2) * (n^2 + n) ) = O(n^2 + n) = O(n^2)
```